# How to populate input text fields with values from database on checkbox clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to automatically populate multiple input text fields with the values of variables returned from SELECT query on click checkbox event. For example: the SELECT query returns Warehouse Street Address ($WarehouseStreetAdress). Then after checking the checkbox "Use the Warehouse Street Address"this address should be entered into input text field. I have the following code:

```
$WarehouseStreetAddress = $_POST['WarehouseStreetAddress']; ...Select query works fine...

<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Use Warehouse Address<br>
Street Address: <input id="StreetAddress" type="text"> 

$("#checkbox").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
    var StreetAddress= $WarehouseStreetAdress;
    }
$("#StreetAddress").val(StreetAddress);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Sounds like you want to use some AJAX? (unless refreshing the page after checkbox click is ok).

Comment: @putvande I just updated the question with the code that i have.

Comment: can you print your $WarehouseStreetAdress console.log($WarehouseStreetAdress);

Comment: You can't mix JavaScript and PHP that way. `var StreetAddress= $WarehouseStreetAdress;` should be something like `var StreetAddress = "<?php echo $WarehouseStreetAdress?>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you mixed PHP with Javascript..

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"> Use Warehouse Address<br>
Street Address: <input id="StreetAddress" type="text"> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#StreetAddress").val("<?php echo $_POST['WarehouseStreetAddress'];?>");
    }
})
</script>
```